# Importing big data in a table for PosgtresDb (stdout is not tty, stdin is not tty) in GitBash

Tags: postgresql, windows, git-bash

```bash
winpty cat table.csv | PGPASSWORD='.......' psql -d db_name -h host_name -U user_name -p $PGPASSWORD -W -p 5432 -c 'COPY name_schema.table_source (column2,columnt3) from STDIN WITH(FORMAT csv, DELIMITER ":",HEADER FALSE)'
```

**Gitbash** is installed on windows.  I am trying to import a large amount of data into a pre-prepared table. However, when I try to do this, I get an error.

> stdout is not tty, stdin is not tty

I tried it without using winpty.

who has any ideas how to fix it ?